# Regex issue for name field - Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I am trying to create a regex which can be used for a name.

```
static let nameRegex =  try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z][A\\p{L}z'\\s]{0,19}$", options: [])
```

I am facing 2 issues:

1. If I type apostrophe, it does not let me type anything further.
2. I am unable to delete the first character on backspace in textfield because of `[a-zA-Z]` in the regex.

I am trying to make it such that it should have a limit of 20 characters, should start with an alphabet, and should allow special characters to accept names such as : **José**, names with apostrophes too.

I am checking the regex like this:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let textFieldText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let filtered: [NSTextCheckingResult] = Constant.Regex.nameRegex.matches(in: textFieldText, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, textFieldText.count))
        return filtered.count == 1
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There are some points about why you might want to avoid such strict checks at [Best REGEX for first/last name validation?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/41163)

Comment: Try `"^(?=\\p{L})[\\p{L}'\\s]{0,20}$"`. Or `"^(?:\\p{L}+(?:[\\s']\\p{L}+)*)?$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for such a prompt reply! I'm sure this is very close, but the first regex does not allow me to type anything after `'`. The second regex does not allow apostrophe at all. Could you please suggest something that fulfills all the criterias listed above

Comment: What if you replace `'` with `\\x27`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Even then I am unable to type anything after the apostrophe

Comment: Then it is surely not related to regex.

Comment: Add the code to your question instead, comments are not suitable for code.

Comment: Please read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: What about `^\w[\w -]{0,20}`, it's somewhat simplified I know but it works nicely with Unicode characters

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, but it doesn't work with apostrophes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad, the apostrophe is working absolutely fine. But the first character isn't getting deleted from textfield. I am using the first regex. Any solution to that?

Comment: Just add the apostrophe to the group inside the brackets `^\w[\w -']{0,20}`.

Comment: @Mamta Try `"^(?!\\P{L})[\\p{L}'\\s]{0,20}$"`, it allows an empty string, if it is not, the first char must be a letter, and the whole string length is capped at 20 chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!! It works perfectly now!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you also give suggestions for same regex which also allows digits from 0-9 but not as the first character

Comment: No idea what you mean. Should this condition be part of the current pattern? What is the string that you want to allow and what is an exmaple string that should not pass?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want same regex to allow all digits too but first character should be an alphabet

Comment: Use `"^(?!\\P{L})[\\p{L}0-9'\\s]{0,20}$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"^(?!\\P{L})[\\p{L}'\\s]{0,20}$"
```

The pattern matches a string that fully matches the following patterns:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\\P{L})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a non-letter char (it requires a letter to the right of the current location or end of string)
- `[\\p{L}'\\s]{0,20}` - 0 to 20 letters, `'` or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This regex works in iOS 10, but not iOS11 onwards. What could the solution be?

Comment: @Mamta Are you sure there is a `'` in your input and not `’`? Try `"^(?!\\P{L})[\\p{L}'’\\s]{0,20}$"`. Also, if there are diacritics use `"^(?!\\P{L})[\\p{L}\\p{M}'’\\s]{0,20}$"`

Comment: Is it possible to modify this regex such that first character is either alphabet or number?

Comment: @Dia You need to add number pattern to the consuming part then and require the first char to be a word char (if any). So use `"^(?!\\W)[\\p{L}0-9'\\s]{0,20}$"`